# Accessing Excel file from word macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open an excel file from a Word Macro, and access data within the Excel file. However, I can only get as far a defining the exWb and I run into the error above. My code is:

```
Sub mySub()

    Dim objExcel As Object
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
    'Dim exWb As Object
    'Set exWb = CreateObject("Excel.Workbook")

    ...

End Sub
```

The issue is with

```
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
```

at which I get the error:

```
Compile error: User-defined type not defined
```

Or

```
Dim exWb As Object
Set exWb = CreateObject("Excel.Workbook")
```

At which I get the error:

```
Run-time error '429':
ActiveX component can't create object
```

Excel 2007 is installed on the PC, and I have added references to Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library, and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library, but this does not help.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Add reference to Microsoft *Excel* XX object library. Also, read up on early VS late binding.

Comment: I have added a reference to the Office Object Library, does that not incorporate Excel? Anyway, I've tried adding the Excel library now and that doesn't help.

Comment: No, Office Object Library doesn't incorporate Excel, it only includes general Office functionality. This problem is solved by either using proper late binding or adding a reference to the Excel object library. No third way about it. Which library did you reference? What error do you get after doing so?

Comment: Like I said, google "late binding VBA"

Comment: Thanks vacip, I added a reference to Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library, and still get the same errors as above. I'll try looking at late binding now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either of two things.
1:
Add reference to the excel object library (see @DisplayName's answer), and rewrite your code a bit:

```
Dim exApp As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Set exWb = exApp.Workbooks.Add
```

This is early binding. Advantage is that it is easier to write the code, as intellisense is helping you. Disadvantage is that if someone tries to run it in a different Office version (e.g Excel 2013), it won't work.

2:
Don't add reference, and use this code:

```
Dim exApp As Object
Set exApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

You are trying to create an excel *application*. In this application you want to create a workbook (`Set exWb = exApp.Workbooks.Add`), etc.

This is late binding, which gives you hard time when coding, but will work regardless of Excel version.

I usually code in early binding, then rewrite the code to late binding when finished.

Comment: Thanks vacip, and sorry that it took me so long to do that.

Answer (score 1):

you have to Add Excel library reference

in VBA IDE, click

- Tools
- References
- select Microsoft Excel XX.0 Object Library
- "OK"

Comment: I have added a reference to the Office Object Library, does that not incorporate Excel? Anyway, I've tried adding the Excel library now and that doesn't help.